# Why is a latitude on a surface of revolution not always locally the shortest path between points?

Tags: differential-geometry

On a surface of revolution given by rotating $[0,f(u),g(u)]$ around the z-axis (with $f(u)>0$) then by Clairaut's theorem we have that a latitude is a geodesic if and only if it is a latitude where $f'(u)=0$, and I understand and accept that.

But my question is, if you have a closed curve on latitude of a surface of revolution where $f'(u) \neq 0$, why would that curve not locally be the shortest path between points?

Like, if you took two points on the same latitude of a surface of revolution, wouldn't the shortest path between those points be on the latitude? Apparently not. Why is this?

Comment: Just think about the situation on a sphere.  I’m sure you know that the only parallel of latitude that’s a geodesic is the equator.

Comment: Simple case: sphere.  Shortest distance between 2 points is great circle between them, not constant latitude line.

Comment: But i mean what if the two points of the sphere lie on the same latitude, then wouldn't they not be able to be connected by a great circle?

Comment: Latitudes are small circles (excpt 0°), take the 89th parallel for example. It is a small circle around the pole. Following it does not give you the shortest path. It is way faster to cut across to get to the other side. Check out [this related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185755/515373)

Comment: Thank you, that made a lot of sense. However, i'm still having trouble visualizing why lines of latitude on a cone are not the shortest paths between two points on the latitude. In this case visualizing a shorter path doesn't work like the example you linked me to because you can't "cut across the north pole"

Comment: Geodesics on a cone are actually straight lines on their unfolded counterpart. You can even do the experiment yourself. With a circular piece of paper with a removed sector, draw straight lines between any points you wish. Then fold it into a cone. You will be able to visualize the path of the geodesic yourself. In some cases, your shortest line will appear to curve a bit towards the apex to get to the other side, even if your points are at the same height from the base of the cone. Mind the cutline, though, sometimes shortest path could cross it!